# pinging vs socket vs push notifications

Tags: enterprise-architecture, real-time, http-response

I develop mobile apps, now im working on a very big project building a tool for the employees to be heavily used. Now the app is on development mode, and testing with few users, but will need to be scalable and have a fast response.

So the question is about the way the thing is being constructed, how it updates the information on "real time".

so we have a list of jobs, in this list some jobs have different status,
the status changes on a job, so from created to submitted to sent etc.

The thing is that the app as is currently based on pings to the server for each job... so there is a lot of pinging...

I have done other kind of connections to avoid that with socket style real time, or with rabbitMQ.

There is also the option of using something like firebase to send "real time" changes, but i don't want to use their database...
The app is already using GCM for push notifications.

When the app is used, it pings the server for changes... So it can ping the server 10 times before getting a status change.

The user base is about 60k workers. Not all of them submitting jobs all the time, but for sure pinging parallel the service.

Now the question is if the ping strategy is correct, how to determine impact on server for the pinging, what would be the best [scalable, speed] approach to have the data sync?

Comment: What you need is a real-time messaging system, so that you can replace inefficient polling (you call it pinging) with real-time pushing. Pushing data can be achieved through WebSockets and through HTTP Streaming. Full disclosure part: I am the CEO of Lightstreamer and we have exactly this kind of technology. more info at www.lightstreamer.com

Comment: Do you mean ICMP ping? How many bits of information are you getting to/from the server this way? If you want something simple, I'd rather use a UDP packet.

Comment: Look into WebSockets. A popular free solution for this is socket.io, and a popular paid solution is Pubnub. I have used both to send fast realtime updates to mobile apps.